# Connecting to remote SQL server using IP address

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005

I dont have so much experience in SQL server. I'm trying to connect to an SQL Server 2005 via IP address. My connection string is:

```
"Data Source=117.213.4.155,1433;Network Library=DBMSSOCN;Initial Catalog=PostDB;User ID="<user>";Password="<password>"
```

I'm getting this error:

> An error has occurred while establishing a connection to the server.  When connecting to SQL Server 2005, this failure may be caused by the fact that under the default settings SQL Server does not allow remote connections. (provider: TCP Provider, error: 0 - No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it.)

I have enabled TCP/IP connection using Surface Configuration tool and I dont have a firewall now.

So how can I solve this? And please give me some advice and insights about storing and retrieving data in remote SQL server. I have no other way to clarify this issue.
Thank you in advance.

Comment: http://www.connectionstrings.com/sql-server-2005

Comment: Thats where I have started. They only provide connection string format, arent they

Comment: Have you tried `ping`, `telnet` this IP?

Comment: Yes I have, there are no problems. And am I using the correct method to access the remote server? Is there any other way?

Comment: I think your method is fine. Maybe the server you are trying to access is protected by some mechanism like VPN or similar?

Comment: Does the SQL server instance have a name? If so, add that to the ip address after a backslash. Is it listening on port 1433? Is the browser service up?

Comment: The sql browser service is running. I installed it with the default instance. I dont know if its listening to the port 1433.

Comment: You say you don't have a firewall.  You disabled the built in windows firewall?

Comment: Yes the windows firewall is disabled since I have Kaspersky Internet Security installed on my current computer, and is there any problems connecting to a dynamic ip because that is what I am doing now.

Comment: Did you restart the service after enabling TCP/IP? That is required.

Answer (score 1):

this article should help

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/914277#method2

Enable remote connections on the instance of SQL Server that you want to connect to from a remote computer.
Turn on the SQL Server Browser service.

Comment: I have enabled remote connections for the instance MSSQLSERVER, and also turned on the browser service. But I'm still getting the error.

Comment: hi Rahul this error message is very generic - tcp provider error 0, check this article checklist [link](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sql_protocols/archive/2007/07/19/tcp-provider-no-connection-could-be-made-because-the-target-machine-actively-refused-it.aspx)

Comment: i have another question. If I use my current machine's ip as datasource, is it similar to using localhost as datasource?

Comment: your connection string is perfectly fine, i don't see any problem in it, its either in the network or sql settings, this might sound silly but some times this error happen if IP address is wrong

Comment: I tried like this. 
Data Source=ip of current machine\\MSSQLSERVER,1433;Network Library=DBMSSOCN;Initial Catalog=PostDB;User ID=sa;Password=
I'm getting the same error. But when Ireplace ip with localhost it works

Comment: replace the ip address with (local), and if your sql instance is the default you dont need to mention it, so no need for [Data Source=ip of current machine\\MSSQLSERVER], just [Data Source=(local)], but if your sql instance is different you type it this way [Data Source=(local)\instancename]

Comment: Another problem. I tried pinging my current machine from another two computers, both said "timed out". I used both private and public ip of my machine, no good. Why is it that I cant ping? I dont have any firewall or anything!

Comment: you might not have a firewall in the network but your windows firewall might be on, check it

Comment: No, the windows firewall is disabled!!

Comment: Rahul, if you can't ping and no firewalls in between your pc and your sql server machine, than probably its a problem in the network, your network admins should fix it.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you can ping the server and the remote server allows connections. Just having an IP address for SQL Server doesn't mean it can be connected. Make sure the server ip is external and accessible from the internet. This is a internet connection issue. Also check the port and everything.

Comment: You mean I should check if the port 1433 is open or not?

Comment: Yes. Also check the firewall. `ping serveraddress:port`

Comment: Dang. I used http://www.whoisxy.com/ping.aspx to ping the ip. I checked both public and private ips. Both resulted in Time out. What needs to be done now?

Comment: The sql server side of the server needs to allow connections. It needs to be done from the server side. Client can't do anything if the sql server is configured that out. Fix the server.